# Can we upload android app on play store which is allow user to download youtube videos?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

In my application i am providing functionality where user can download youtube videos so i am not sure whether it is legal to provide download functionality or not?

Comment: You probably need to check google/youtube licenses/playstore licenses yourself.
But i do not think, that google would allow such app in the play store.

Comment: @PhilipB I also read all documents regarding new youtube API policy, and also show some application that provides the same feature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming

Comment: [Where to ask legal questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240883/where-to-ask-legal-questions-on-programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what [Youtube's Term of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) has to say:

> **You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or
>   similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content**. You
>   shall not copy, reproduce, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display,
>   sell, license, or otherwise exploit any Content for any other purposes
>   without the prior written consent of YouTube or the respective
>   licensors of the Content. YouTube and its licensors reserve all rights
>   not expressly granted in and to the Service and the Content.